# In 2021 when the xmr algo is RandomX which hardware is most efficient

Tags: xmr-stak

i am just mining on cpu thats an xeon 1230 and i get around 1.2KHs i am thinking to scale it up and looking for an appropriate hardware but i see that gpus arent that efficient to mine xmr
please help electricity is not an issue

Answer (score 1):

You can find here a compilation of some hardware mining specific for monero:

https://monerobenchmarks.info/